# How to speed up bulk reads from PostgreSQL with JDBC?

Tags: postgresql, performance, jdbc

I have a feature that needs to read millions of rows from a PostgreSQL database. Yes, this sounds like an XY problem but the data is already in Postgres and it has to be processed in bulk daily in a way that cannot be done in the database.

In my test case there are 8 million rows that take up about 10 GB of space in JSON format. Right now reading the data takes more than 10 minutes. I am reading it by issuing a `select` query and iterating over the results with `ResultSet.next`. The equivalent `select count(*)` is almost instant and the rows start to get returned to JDBC quickly so there is little upfront lag. The performance issue is in getting the rows from point A to point B. Note that I experience similar performance with `copy (...) to stdout`.

Are there any techniques / settings to get the data to load faster? Or am I doomed since this is a use case that databases are not optimized for?

---

We are using Postgres Server 9.6.8 on Amazon RDS and Java 8.

Comment: If you find a way to process the data inside the database, for example in a function, you would be faster.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes I'm sure it would be. Unfortunately in our case it isn't practical to do that. We have a lot of custom processing, including combining with data from other sources, that doesn't translate nicely to SQL.

Comment: But maybe to Perl or Python in a function.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. In our case I think it's a long shot because we're using Amazon RDS and the DB server probably wouldn't have access to our other data sources. But that wasn't specified in the question.

Comment: Try to enable fetching with a cursor: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor